# How to use Like Operator with "_" in MyBatis

Tags: mybatis

I want to search "parent_id" with underscore "_"

t.parent_id like '%'+#parentPartID#+'%'

I want the results  only _xxx or xx_xx or xxx_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ESCAPE` subclause to specify escape symbol and use it to escape underscore which is special symbol handled by `LIKE`: `t.parent_id LIKE '%\_%' ESCAPE '\'`